# FIX protocol: Sending broker authorizations in a FIX message in the beginning of the trading day

Tags: fix-protocol

I 'm not sure if this falls under the scope of this forum but I could not find a more relevant one.

I am working in the FIX protocol team of an asset manager and we have had multiple issues with sending the list of authorized or restricted counterparties to the elctronic platforms, within the FIX message of every  new order. I was therefore wondering if there exists the possibility, to send a single FIX message in the beginning of the day stating that in this FIX session and for the rest of the day we have the following list of restricted or authorized counterparties.

Does anyone know if such a workflow exists?

Kind regards,
Theo

PS I have looked into the list of messages mentioned in https://fiximate.fixtrading.org/ and I am not sure if any of them corresponds to my request but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Hi, what particular issues are you speaking of?

Comment: Also don't know exactly what you are speaking of. Did you take a look at the `PartyEntitlement*`messages? There you could specify which parties are entitled to trade, submit quote requests, etc... But maybe I misunderstood your question?!

Comment: Hello, so for example when it comes to list orders our OMS does not send the list of authorized counterparties on block level but instead includes the list in each order of the basket. Thus the FIX message we end up with can be enormous and not supported by the trading platforms to whom we send the message.